How do you only download new parts of a main branch in Github without redownloading the whole project again?
I'm part of a repo with a couple friends and I want to know how to download only the new parts of the main branch in a way where I dont have to redownload the whole game from the beginning every time? Btw if it helps I'm coding the game on Godot.
I've scoured the internet and Youtube and I can't really find anything for 2024 and it seems like such a basic feature that I think I'm missing something.

This is a git question. When you clone the repo, it will download the whole project from the remote repo. After that, everytime anyone push new changes to a branch and you want to apply that changes to your local repo, you checkout that branch then fetch and pull. Git will compare what is different between remote and your local repo and only download the differences. Please learn more about how git works (or version control in general) and how to apply it to your works, it will do you wonders.
